# Finding two strings with a maximum number of characters between them

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a list of keywords call it [cat, dog, bird] and a regex to find a weight (\dlbs).

I only want to find items that

1. start with the items in the array

   - (cat|dog|bird?)
2. match the weight regex

   - (\dlbs)
3. only have a max of 30 characters (excluding whitespace) between 1. and 2.

   - do not want to or care to capture the 1-30 characters

Any help appreciated!

Comment: what is the string you are having ?

Comment: The downvotes (and votes to close) are from readers who believe your question is unclear.  Does the string look like `"cat 20lbs, dog 60 lbs, bird 450lbs"` or `"My cat weighs 20 lbs, my dog, 60 lbs, big bird tips at 450 lbs"` or something else? Is each "item" you want to find an array (e.g., `['dog', 60]`), a substring (`'dog is 60 lbs'`) or something else?  Think of this in terms of a method `doit(str)`.  What do you want `doit` to return for each of several example strings (including 'edge cases' like "cat dog 40 lbs").  Do this by editing you question (not with a comment), without delay.

Comment: I apologize, one of the hard parts of SO is that you have to ask a question, while obsfucating the actual data enough to satisfy .. "clients". While I did discover my (stupid) mistake, I feel like Ed should get credit for his timely and appropriate answer. However if you decide to close it, I would understand.

Comment: It's not too late to try to save the question by editing.  (I did not downvote, as I felt it could be a good question if clarified.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
(cat|dog|bird)\s*(?:(?:\S\s*){0,30})(\dlbs)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tkxFJl-oYwmycRO6)

*Edited to reflect the "excluding whitespace" point.*

It matches, for example, each of the following:

```
The cat weighs almost exactly 7lbs.
The cat weighs                         almost exactly 7lbs
```

Note: you appear to have a stray `?` in your question in `(cat|dog|bird?)` - I have ignored it. Also, are you sure you will have `\dlbs`, not, say, `17 lbs` or `17 pounds`? You can easily address those scenarios with

```
(cat|dog|bird)\s*(?:(?:\S\s*){0,30})(\d\s*(?:lb|pound)s)
```

Comment: Thanks Ed! I tried that, but doesnt seem to capture what I'm looking to do..

Comment: How so? The whitespace part?

Comment: See my edit to address the whitespace issue.

Answer (score 1):

`(\s*.){0,30}` Maximum 30 characters excluding white spaces:

```
(cat|dog|bird)(\s*.){0,30}\s*(\dlbs)
```